# How can I zoom on pinchIn/pinchOut in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have written the events. I dont get how to do the pinchIn pinchOut programmatically. Please help me. And I am using TouchSwipe plugin. I tried:

```
pinchIn: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, pinchZoom) {
    console.log('pinchIn');
    $(this).css('zoom','1.5');        
},
pinchOut:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, pinchZoom) {
    $(this).css('zoom','1.0');
    console.log('pinchOut');         
},
```

Comment: maybe try with iscroll...

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are setting the css() function to zoom in a static amount each time. You should add some kind of increment every time the event is fired, so you zoom in "further" each time. Here's a really simple example of what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/x4gkoeos/

So for example

```
var pinchAmount = 0; // not sure what you'd set this to for your use case

pinchIn: function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, pinchZoom) {
    console.log('pinchIn');
    $(this).css('zoom', pinchAmount);    
    pinchAmount = pinchAmount + 1 // Or whatever you want the increment to be, I'm guessing 1
}
```